# How to take an input in asterix WHILE typing?

Tags: java, user-input

I have to create a login id which takes a password(in java) but I want the input to be in asterix while the user types to make it look professional. Is it even possible? Please give the syntax for the code to be input as asterix.

If the question has been asked before (i could not find it) please link before removing.
Thank You.

Comment: Where is the user typing this password? A website? A form application? A console application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get password from console try the following:

```
    Console console = System.console();
    if (console == null) {
        System.out.println("Couldn't get Console instance");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    char passwordArray[] = console.readPassword("Enter your password: ");
    console.printf("Password entered was: %s%n", new String(passwordArray));
```